# Install all packages used in testing suite in R?

Tags: r, devtools, testthat

I'm trying to submit a PR to `library(broom)` which relies on testing a bunch of different libraries. Is there a quick way to install all the packages used in the testing suite?

Comment: You mean test `revdeps`?

Comment: You can check `packrat`

Comment: These are not dependencies of the code but of the tests. Broom converts model output to tidy data.frames. All of the tests load different modeling packages and tests expected output. These packages are listed in the "Suggests" portion of the DESCRIPTION file.

Comment: `?install.packages` in dependencies maybe? **logical indicating whether to also install uninstalled packages which these packages depend on/link to/import/suggest (and so on recursively). Not used if repos = NULL. Can also be a character vector, a subset of c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances").**

Comment: @NelsonGon post as  answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can specify specific dependencies we need to install as follows(You can specify only `Suggests` for instance:

```
install.packages("broom", dependencies = c("Suggests","Enhances",
                                           "Depends"))
```

More information on available options can be found in the help page of `install.packages`. For this question, the relevant information is:

> dependencies   logical indicating whether to also install uninstalled packages which these packages depend on/link to/import/suggest (and so on recursively). Not used if repos = NULL. Can also be a character vector, a subset of c("Depends", "Imports", "LinkingTo", "Suggests", "Enhances").
>
> Only supported if lib is of length one (or missing), so it is unambiguous where to install the dependent packages. If this is not the case it is ignored, with a warning.